# Trace interruption on a linux system

Tags: linux-kernel, trace, interrupt

The command `strace` is mainly for tracing system call.
Does someone know the equivalent for tracing interruption like IRQ14...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strace` is only useful for tracing userspace activity. In order to trace interrupts properly you need an in-kernel tracing solution. Check out the following. `ftrace` is probably your best bet. Note, however, that these have a fairly high learning curve, but that is expected.

- http://lwn.net/Articles/370423/
- http://www.mail-archive.com/linuxkernelnewbies@googlegroups.com/msg02422.html
- http://lttng.org/
- SystemTap is also a good choice.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/).  You may need to patch your kernel to allow SystemTap to extract the information you want, though.  It's kind of a mess.

Answer (score 3):

Hardware interrupts may be counted with systemtap (or perf or ftrace):

`# stap -e 'global irq;  probe kernel.trace("irq_handler_entry") {irq[$irq]<<<1}' -c WORKLOAD-COMMAND`

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the number of interrupts through `/proc/interrupts`. Without specific kernel hacking that's probably the best you can get from userland. What more would you want to trace?

Comment: I would like to know all interrupt that occur during an execution

Comment: an execution of who? please be a little more specific.

Comment: like the stract.

`$ strace ls`

Comment: You said that, yes. Strace shows system calls: things a program needs to be done by the kernel, such as I/O. Now, the question is: what are you looking for? Interrupts are hardware signals, and you can at the very least count them. That's what you can use `/proc/interrupts` for. What do you want to see, other than that?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at **[oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html)**.